# An SQL query to derive data from one to many rows based on another field

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have an issue I can't get my head around. This is the table:

Table1

```
c1      c2      c3
1       A
2       A       DD
3       A       DD
4       B       HH
5       B     
6       B
```

This is the desired outcome:

```
c1      c2      c3
1       A       DD
2       A       DD
3       A       DD
4       B       HH
5       B       HH
6       B       HH
```

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.4. Basically I want to use the non-null values in c3 to fill c3 based on the common data the rows have in c2.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you want the "first" non-null value for the c3 column for the "group" that is defined through the c2 column.

This can be done with a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
select c1, 
       c2, 
       first_value(c3) over (partition by c2 order by c3 nulls last) as c3
from table_1
```

This does return the result you showed us.

**Edit** (after the question was changed)

To update the existing values you can use this:

```
update t1
  set c3 = tu.c3
from (
  select c1, c2, first_value(c3) over (partition by c2 order by c3 nulls last) as c3
  from t1
) tu
where t1.c1 = tu.c1
  and t1.c3 is null;
```

Comment: Hey a_horse_with_no_name -- thanks a lot for the help! Your query works brilliantly but it's not saving to table1. Is there something I can type in to effect this back to the table itself?

Comment: @gislipals: what do yo mean with "saving to table". Of course it's not "saving" anything, it's a select statement.

Comment: oh, I'm trying to update c3 so that every row with matching c2 have matching c3. does that make sense?

Comment: @gislipals: see my edit

Comment: worked like a charm - thanks again @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the desired result you need to join your table to itself and then ignore those rows where c3 is null. The SQL below produces the required result. I'm not a PostgreSQL person so there may be a better way to do this.

```
 Create Table Test
 (
  C1 int,
  C2 char(1),
  c3 char(2) NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO TEST values( 1,       'A',NULL); 
 INSERT INTO TEST values( 2 ,      'A','DD');
 INSERT INTO TEST values( 3 ,      'A',NULL);
 INSERT INTO TEST values( 4 ,      'B','HH');
 INSERT INTO TEST values( 5 ,      'B',NULL )  ;  
 INSERT INTO TEST values( 6  ,     'B',NULL);

 select * From TEST T
 join 
 Test t2
 ON t.C2=T2.c2
 and t2.c3 is not null;
```